# Android detects clicks when it shouldn't

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an image button and associated click handler.

When I animate button (using translate animation) the button, obviously, changes it's position on screen.

But there is a problem: Android detects clicks when I touch initial button location and not the current.

How can I make Android respect actual location of the button?

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="plusButtonClick"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    public void plusButtonClick(View v)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        animateButton(R.id.addButton, R.anim.anim_move);
    }

    private void animateButton(int buttonId, int animationId)
    {
        View button = findViewById(buttonId);
        AnimationSet animationSet = (AnimationSet)AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, animationId);
        animationSet.setAnimationListener(getStartingButtonsListener(button));
        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        button.startAnimation(animationSet);
    }

    private Animation.AnimationListener getStartingButtonsListener(final View v)
    {
        return new Animation.AnimationListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0)
            {
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**anim_move.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="true"
     android:fillAfter="true"
     android:duration="1000">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="180"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="0"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem here : [Button moves to different part of screen but can only press it at its initial spot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550275/button-moves-to-different-part-of-screen-but-can-only-press-it-at-its-initial-sp)

The animation is animating the pixels, not the touch zones of a widget.
You need to animate the properties as well : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

Answer (score 1):

The translate animation doesn't actually move your object, it just moves the image of it. You should reposition your button yourself at the end of the animation by editing its `LayoutParams`

Answer (score 0):

Use onTouchEvent for your button. Moreover, give this onTouch implementation through java file, but not with the XML layout file. This is far better than using onClick event.
See this : [Triggering event when Button is pressed down in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615616/triggering-event-when-button-is-pressed-down-in-android)